Why didn't Koji Kabuto have Mazinger Z anymore in the 80's Grendizer series?
Here in the late 80's, they aired Grendizer. I knew there was another cartoon called Mazinger airing in another network, my cousin would talk to me about Mazinger, there were toys around and everything, and I knew the Mazinger robot looked similar to the Grendizer robot, they were the only robots from that time who  detached their arms and threw them to their enemies, but I didnt know which the relation betweeen the cartoons (animes) was.
Then with internet, I read about Koji Kabuto from Grendizer being the pilot of Mazinger Z, but in the Grendizer series he just pilots an UFO-like spaceship and a "spazer".
What happened with Mazinger Z in the Grendizer series, why didn't Koji Kabuto have it anymore?

According to Wikipedia, there was a series inbetween those two, "Great Mazinger". During that series, a new robot (the Great Mazinger) was constructed, and arrived just in time to save the day as a new enemy destroyed Mazinger Z. Koji survived, and left Japan after the battle to study in America.
(It may even have been that this happened in the Mazinger Z series finale, with the Great Mazinger series being set after the battle.)
The Grendizer article tells us about how Grendizer came to Earth later, and about how Koji became the sidekick to its pilot, Daisuke aka Duke Fleed. There was also a crossover of dubious canonicity in which Koji was captured and mind-controlled, then forced to attack Grendizer with Great Mazinger (Grendizer was being piloted by Daisuke). Grendizer won.
I don't know if very much of this was changed in the American localisation, but Wikipedia does say: "In addition, footage from Great Mazinger's sole appearance in the final episode of Mazinger Z was aired as part of the US version of Mazinger Z, known as Tranzor Z." Anyway, all of this is from the original 70s (in Japan)/80s (in America) show, not the remake as mentioned in the other answer.

That's a great answer, but what happened to the Great Mazinger then? And who piloted it, because I assume it wasnt Koji Kabuto since he piloted an aircraft in the series.

I don't know what happened to Great Mazinger. In the dubiously-canon crossover it sounds like it's just in a hangar somewhere, but there's not much detail. Grendizer is apparently set a few years after Koji left Japan, and he's just returned to Japan, so it can't be a matter of "Great Mazinger is fighting enemies in Japan while Grendizer fights villains somewhere else." The Great Mazinger pilot is someone called Tetsuya Tsurugi , an orphan who was raised by Koji's father.

A (apparent) remake of Grendizer was just released. I said apparent because it looks like a remake to me, but it could be a sequel or spinoff, not sure, they just aired one episode. In it, they show how Duke Fleed arrived to Earth. And unlike the original (80's) version, we see Mazinger Z fights Duke Fleed's enemies and Mazinger Z is destroyed, to be saved by Grendizer. The very cool thing is we see Mazinger Z and Grendizer in the same episode, and they show Grendizer is more powerful than Mazinger Z

Though I rewatched the original 80's first episode, and no mention of Mazinger Z whatsoever, I don't know if it's mentioned in another episode or something, but we just see Koji Kabuto flying his flying saucer shaped spaceship created by him.

–1 For gratuitous use of spoiler tags.

@lexible what are you talking about? I dont understand what you mean, there was a spoiler, I used the spoiler tag and that's wrong?

@lexible if you mean the spoiler wasnt needed even covered, it actually is, because it's an answer to the original question

@Pablo If it's the answer to the original question, then it shouldn't be hidden in spoiler tags. Those trying to avoid spoilers would know well to avoid the answer just by reading the question. I suggest using spoiler markup sparingly. Relevant meta posts regarding spoiler protection: [1] [2].

@galacticninja ok, spoiler tags gone. I hope I dont get people now complaining there are spoilers

This remake might be Grendizer U, as mentioned in this Wikipedia article. Forbes confirms that it does have Koji piloting the original Mazinger Z, unlike in the original series.
